# How do I upgrade KeePass2 to the newest version from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, keepass

How do I upgrade KeePass2 using the terminal ?
I have version 2.25 and I want to upgrade to version 2.30.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [KeePass repository](https://launchpad.net/~jtaylor/+archive/ubuntu/keepass) :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:jtaylor/keepass
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install keepass2
```

With this PPA KeePass will automatically be updated when you run `sudo apt-get upgrade`
(or when running the Update Manager).

Note that http://keepass.info/help/v2/setup.html is not recommending using any private ppa.